# Mount a usb disk with udev. permission denied

Tags: mount, udev

I would like to automatically mount a usb disk when I plug it.

I believed udev is the solution, so I created `/etc/udev/rules.d/99_extern_hdd.rules` that only contains:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="1058", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="25a2", RUN+="/etc/mount_extern.sh"
```

The script `/etc/mount_extern.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -dl /media  > /tmp/output
ls -dl /media/data >> /tmp/output
echo "mount ${DEVNAME} /media/data" >> /tmp/output
mount ${DEVNAME} /media/data >> /tmp/output 2>&1
```

But when I plug my disk the output ( `/tmp/output` created by `/etc/mount_extern.sh`) gives me:

```
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Aug 14 10:47 /media
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 18  2017 /media/data
mount /dev/sde1 /media/data
mount: /media/data: permission denied.
```

I don't understand why I have this `permission denied`. The rights of the folder seem good no?
also when I do `sudo mount /dev/sde1 /media/data`, it works fine

Any idea?

My OS is Linux archlinux 5.8.10-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu, 17 Sep 2020 18:01:06 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run `mount` from UDev rule. From UDev manpage:

> Note that running programs that access the network or mount/unmount
> filesystems is not allowed inside of udev rules, due to the default
> sandbox that is enforced on systemd-udevd.service.

You can use `systemd-mount` or other tools, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Mounting_drives_in_rules